# python upload file with curl

Tags: python, curl, file-upload, browserstack

i'm trying to upload an apk to server
the code i used to upload using curl is written like this:

```
curl -u "musername:mypass" -X POST "https://myurl/upload" -F "file=@D:\path\to\location.apk"
```

i tried to make a script using python with `requests` library like this:

```
response = requests.post(
            self.urlUpload,
            files={"file" : open(self.apkLocation, 'r')},
            auth=(self.BSUsername, self.BSToken)
        )
```

but it gives me errors:

```
{"error":"Malformed archive"}
```

anyone knows why this erros appeared?

Comment: Try reading it in `rb` ?

Comment: You also need to set the content type headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a chance to try something like below?

```
import requests

    files = {
        'file': ('/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk', open('/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk', 'rb')),
    }
    response = requests.post('https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload', 
                files=files, 
                auth=('BSUsername ', 'BSToken'))
    print (response.text)#THE APP URL (bs://<hashed appid>) RETURNED IN THE RESPONSE OF THIE CALL
```

Check the BrowserStack REST API doc [here](https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/rest-api)

Comment: Welcome and nice answer Maddy! Thumbs up for including the link, however you could improve your answer by explaining your code or including comments. This way people may have a better chance of understanding if they're not experts :)

Comment: ah exactly! i replaced the "r" flag with "rb" flag just like yours and that works. thanks!